# Почему в TStringGrid сдвигается заголовок?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

Нужно кое-что сделать в последней версии C++ Builder XE8. Использую TStringGrid, но сдвигается заголовок по сравнению c TDBGrid или старой версией C++ Builder 6. Предполагаю, что в Delphi XE8 тоже самое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проверьте `margin` для `title`

Comment: Не нашёл там такого...

Comment: Можете дать текстовый файл формы *.dfm легче было бы проверить.

Comment: Создаёшь новую форму и просто бросаешь на неё TStringGrid, потом заполняешь её... тоже самое